# How to retrieve keys from nest() in d3.v3.min.js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am writing a code to find the top 6 activities based on the number of the ids.
CSV is like:
10000   Electricity Bill Payment
10001   Water Bill Payment
10002   Gas Bill Payment
10003   Electricity Bill Payment
10001   Water Bill Payment
10001   Water Bill Payment

My code is :

```
d3.csv("activities.csv", function(error,data) {
//fetching and storing the activities as key and their individual count as value
countByActivties=  d3.nest()
       .key(function(d) { return d.ACTIVITY; })//.sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; }).sortValues(d3.descending)
      //.sortValues(d3.ascending)
      //.sortValues(function(v, d){ return d3.ascending(d.length); })
      .entries(data);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(countByActivties));
```

The output is like:

```
[{"key":"Electricity Bill Payment","values":2},{"key":"Water Bill Payment","values":3},{"key":"Gas Bill Payment","values":1}]
```

For finding the top 6 activites based on their count(i.e sort by descending order on the count). I have tried the getKeys function, but is not working. Below is code snippet for the same:

```
 for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        countByActivties.getKeys(function(d){ return d.key;})
    }
```

the error it is throwing is:

```
testchartfunction.html:56 Uncaught TypeError: countByActivties.getKeys is not a function.
```

What I am trying to do is to iterate along the key values to fetch the data.

Anyone any idea about the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you just want the top 6 elements in the array and then get its keys:

Instead of this

```
 for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        countByActivties.getKeys(function(d){ return d.key;});//there is no getKeys function in an array.
    }
```

do this:

```
var keys = countByActivties
          .sort(function(a, b){return a.values-b.values})
          .slice(0,6)
          .map(function(d){ return d.key;})
```

First sort then get the to 6 elements.

Then extract the key from the 6 elements.

Comment: Thanks Cyril for the reply. But I have to fetch the top 6 activities. i.e. 6 activities with the maximum number of counts. its should come as "[{"key":"Water Bill Payment","values":3},{"key":"Electricity Bill Payment","values":2},{"key":"Gas Bill Payment","values":1}]"

Comment: Changed my answer to handle sort.

Comment: Cyril. i have further added the duration colum to my csv and i am trying to calculate the average of the top six activites:  `  actvtsByAvgdrtn = d3.nest()
       .key(function(d) { 
       for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        if(keys[i] == d.ACTIVITY){return d.ACTIVITY;}
        else return "hello"
       }
         })
      .rollup(function(v) { return d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.DURATION; }); })
      .entries(data);})'

Comment: i am getting the error: "testchartfunction.html:49 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" ....... any idea what wrong is there in the code.

Comment: Not sure...what is there on line no 49..may be that could help